# Ramanujan and algebraic number theory

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, ramanujan

One out of the almost endless supply of identities discovered by Ramanujan
is the following:
$$ \sqrt[3]{\rule{0pt}{2ex}\sqrt[3]{2}-1} = \sqrt[3]{\frac19} - \sqrt[3]{\frac29} + \sqrt[3]{\frac49}, $$
which has the following interpretation in algebraic number theory: the fundamental unit
$\sqrt[3]{2}-1$ of the pure cubic number field $K = {\mathbb Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$ becomes a cube in the extension $L = K(\sqrt[3]{3})$.

Are there more examples of this kind in Ramanujan's work?

Comment: Dear Matt: $2^{1/3} - 1$ is a fundamental unit, so probably that is what Franz meant to write. 

Answer (score 17, accepted):

$$(7 \sqrt[3]{20} - 19)^{1/6} = \ \sqrt[3]{\frac{5}{3}}
- \sqrt[3]{\frac{2}{3}},$$
$$\left( \frac{3 + 2 \sqrt[4]{5}}{3 - 2 \sqrt[4]{5}}
\right)^{1/4}= \  \  \frac{\sqrt[4]{5} + 1}{\sqrt[4]{5} - 1},$$
$$\left(\sqrt[5]{\frac{1}{5}} + \sqrt[5]{\frac{4}{5}}\right)^{1/2}
=  \  \ (1 + \sqrt[5]{2} + \sqrt[5]{8})^{1/5} =  \ \ 
\sqrt[5]{\frac{16}{125}} + \sqrt[5]{\frac{8}{125}} + \sqrt[5]{\frac{2}{125}} - \sqrt[5]{\frac{1}{125}},$$
and so on. Many of these were submitted by Ramanujan as problems to the
Journal of the Indian Mathematical Society. See the following link:
[jims.ps](https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/%7Eberndt/jims.ps) for more precise references.
Quote: "although Ramanujan never used the term unit, and
probably did not formally know what a unit was,
he evidently realized their fundamental properties.
He then recognized that taking certain powers of units
often led to elegant identities."

Comment: I would have gone with 'enery
$$ $$
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I'm_Henery_the_Eighth,_I_Am

Comment: Not a real link, in an answer rather than a comment, even if the wikipedia link has extra punctuation, one can click on the hyperlink symbol and convince MO to make the entire character string into a genuine link.

Comment: Excellent. I had no idea the song went back to 1910.